# On Linux, can you be notified when a network port is used and generate logs?

Tags: linux, networking, port

I'm trying to write a script that detects and logs when a network port is opened/closed.

For example, say I open a port and close it using npm's `http-server` package:

```
$ npx http-server -p 8080
[ctrl^c]
$ npx http-server -p 8080
[ctrl^c]
```

I'd like the logs to read

```
Port opened on 8080
Port closed on 8080
Port opened on 8080
Port closed on 8080
```

My end goal is to write a program that automatically forwards opened ports via an SSH tunnel for my VM/host - so it's important that I am able to intercept this event.

Is it possible to do this from a shell script or is there a kernel module with an exposed C interface (new to this) I could talk to from a Rust application?

Comment: Would it be an option to write a wrapper script instead?